Bundling for "Isolated Worlds" in Chrome Browser Extension
I'm thinking about how I can structure my code.
Since some code in Chrome Browser runs in "Isolated Worlds", little VMs, I have trouble bundling my Javascript without creating a lot of duplicated code.
For my browser extension, I want to add a listener, that has a callback function someFunctionToUnpack.
// typescript
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'DO_STH') {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const tab = tabs[0];
      if (tab && tab.id !== undefined) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tab.id as number },
          func: someFunctionToUnpack, // Type: func: () => void
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

Ideally, it contains code that I can re-use in other places, because I do need this code in other places.
// typescript
import { some } from "anotherFile.ts";

const anotherFunctionCall = ()=> {
  return some.objectContainingFunctions();
}
const doSomthingWithA = (a)=> {
  console.log(a);
}

const someFunctionToUnpack() {
  const a = anotherFunctionCall()
  doSomethingWithA(a);
}

If I did that, my current settings compile in a way that object() of some is not defined.
// In the VM, which has got the callback and
// is now isolated from the rest of the compiled javascript:
(()=>{
  const e = (()=>{
    const e = {
      some.objectContainingFunctions() // breaks here
    };
    console.log(e);
  })()
}
)()

While in a normal environment, we would bundle everything to the absolut minimum, I
require some code to be fully unpack and intentionally be duplicated, so that callback from event listeners in Chrome extensions can have access to their references, while I still avoid writing duplicated code.
Because it breaks in the VM, I'm forced to copy and move code into the someFunctionToUnpack and create duplicated code.
I'm using Webpack 5
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'service-worker': './src/service-worker.ts',
    'content': './src/content.ts',
    'index': './src/backend/index.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    clean: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        chunks: ['index'],
      }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json' },
        { from: 'src/icons', to: 'icons' },
        { from: 'src/styles', to: 'styles' },
      ]
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        compress: true,
        mangle: true
      }
    })],
  },
};


Instead of injecting a function, inject the entire file e.g. content.js that imports the function(s). This way the code will be duplicated (as it should), but automatically by webpack in the output bundle for content.js

@woxxom can you give an example?  I tried inside file, outside file, creating classes, turning the object into exported functions. I'm totally lost. Also interestingly, it keeps unpacking the first level functions. And sometimes I find it unpacking the first property of my 'some' object, but not the rest.

Simply don't use func, i.e. make a separate content.js and use files in executeScript. To transfer data you can use messaging. There are lots of examples, that's the standard and clean approach, no hacks necessary. Also note that executeScript + func is internally inefficient, because every time it runs it serializes the function's source code into string which is then executed in the tab. With files you would inject the code just once, either via executeScript or via content_scripts in manifest.json.

Thanks @woxxom I updated my answer. Just one note: I usually post rarely on Stackoverflow, because there is indeed a lot of examples on the internet. For this case I either didn't have the right keywords, or there is none. Rest assured, I spent hours with searching on multiple search engines and platforms.

Sorry, if you meant an example of configuring webpack, I misunderstood, because I'm not using it.

Update using files instead of func.
In Webpack concatenate everything you need in your separate JS file. Webpack will take care to collect everything from imports.
entry: {
    'service-worker': './src/service-worker.ts',
    'content': './src/content.ts',
    'index': './src/backend/index.ts',
    'yourSeparateFile': './src/your/entry/path/to/your/separateFile.ts'
  },

In your listener, instead of func define files.
//...
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
   target: { tabId: tab.id as number },
   files: ['yourSeparateFile.js'],
});
//...


In your file:
// separateFile.ts

// Define your function and imports here
// and call your function here as well.


The not recommended version:
It feels a bit hacky, but I guess I can create a good refactoring out of it that also leads to good reusable and clean code.
Whatever function I have would need to be part of an object and that object needs to be returned from another function.
// yourFunction.ts
// This can also be a named function in the same file of wherever you want to inject it
export default () => {
  return {
    yourProperty: (parameter) => {
      // do stuff...
    }
  }
}

// later in the file or another file
import YF from "./yourFunction";

export const someFunctionToUnpack = () => {
  const yourFunction = YF();
  yourFunction.yourProperty();
}

And this can be used for the func of the chrome.scripting.executeScript. It will appear in the browser's VM and fulfil the need for "isolated worlds".
